# Strange HTML5 video issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

Please take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rwbcf/

## If we have 16:9 display:

[image]

## Problem occurs when we have display with aspect ratio other than 16:9.

You cansee big empty space at the bottom of video and as much we resize browser window (get width smaller) empty space grows more and more.

[image]

Is there any solution like scaling, or cropping and zooming to remove this empty space? I can't figure out. Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<div id="video-viewport">

        <video id="bg" autoplay loop preload="none" tabindex="0">

           <source src="http://goo.gl/MkY4i" type="video/mp4" />

       </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    min-width:100%;
    background:#000;
    overflow:hidden;
}

body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 ;
}
#bg {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

#video-viewport {
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
    z-index: -1; /* for accessing the video by click */
}
```

Comment: as far as I know, the video's going to try to play at its native aspect ratio unless forces to distort. put some height/width on the video, e.g. 100% for both, so it'll try to follow the viewport's sizing. 'course, that'll quickly look ugly if you change the window to a goofy ratio

Comment: @MarcB scaling and filling, or scaling and cropping can do work

Answer (score 4):

The specification for the video element says that this should happen, it is the equivalent of the following CSS:

```
video { object-fit: contain; }
```

You can change this if you don't mind the aspect ratio being ignored:

```
video { object-fit: fill; }
```

Or if you want to effectively zoom in (preserve aspect ration, but crop portions)

```
video { object-fit: cover; }
```

You can [check out browser support for the object-fit property](http://caniuse.com/object-fit).

Comment: you'd better try it first on fiddle the write as an answer. It doesn't work at all

Comment: Did you read the link on browser support? I included that because this feature has low support today.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue, although the empty space appears above and underneath like in a panoramic movie - this is completely unwanted behavior.

Setting:
  video { object-fit: fill; }

works for me perfectly well!

Answer (score 0):

to remove the black space , video size should be as the container size so add this to your css:

```
#video-viewport {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;    
}
```